# Google Places API: Cannot get review summary

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I followed the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details), and tried the following query:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?parameters&extensions=review_summary&placeid=ChIJ-UoSVL6-woARN7jRAL3Xigk&key=<MY_OWN_KEY>
```

, but the result doesn't contain any review summary and looks like this:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "...",
            "short_name" : "...",
            "types" : [ "street_number" ]
         },
         ...
      ],
      "adr_address" : "...",
      "formatted_address" : "...",
      "formatted_phone_number" : "...",
      "geometry" : {
         "location" : {
            "lat" : ...,
            "lng" : ...
         },
         ...
         }
      },
      "icon" : "...",
      "id" : "...",
      "international_phone_number" : "...",
      "name" : "...",
      "opening_hours" : {...],
         "weekday_text" : [...]
      },
      "photos" : [...],
      "place_id" : "ChIJ-UoSVL6-woARN7jRAL3Xigk",
      "rating" : ...,
      "reference" : "...",
      "reviews" : [
         {
            "author_name" : "...",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/.../reviews",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/.../photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 5,
            "relative_time_description" : "in the last week",
            "text" : "The hotel was clean. The bed was comfortable and the hotel was quiet. The breakfast was hot and good with a variety of choices. The check in was easy and the staff were happy to accommodate us with an early check-in and late checkout.  The pool was clean and beautiful.  Parking was convenient and easy to access.  I felt safe in the hotel and in the parking garage. It was a great stay.",
            "time" : 1500747721
         },
         {...},
         {...},
         {...},
         {...}
      ],
      "scope" : "GOOGLE",
      "types" : [ "lodging", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
      "url" : "https://maps.google.com/?cid=...",
      "utc_offset" : ...,
      "vicinity" : "...",
      "website" : "..."
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

However, from Google Maps, this hotel does have an editorial review summary:

```
Rooms · 3.8  
Guests liked the large, clean rooms, though some said they were dated & maintenance could be improved · Guests appreciated the large bathrooms
Location · 4.6  
Easily accessible by car; parking available · Sightseeing, restaurants & bars nearby
Service & facilities · 4.3  
Guests enjoyed the pool · Guests spoke highly of the reception staff
```

Am I understanding `review_summary` wronlgy? If not, can anyone give a `place_id` that upon request does return a review summary? I love Google Maps, and simply want to see a review summary (could be any) returned by the API at this point.

Do I need to upgrade to a premium plan to see review summary? It says,

```
Additional fields may include premium data, requiring an additional license, or values that are not commonly requested. Extensions are currently experimental.
```

If so, can anyone from Google or having used the premium plan before confirm this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't see the instructions for the review_summary on the linked page. Perhaps they removed this functionality? I was also looking for the same thing.

Comment: "Warning: The premium data (Zagat) feature is no longer supported after May 2, 2017. Zagat ratings and reviews will no longer be available from that point on. The search parameter zagatselected is no longer accepted and the fields aspects , review_summary and zagat_selected are no longer returned with search results." as per https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search?hl=de (but not mentioned on the English page)